# How to change cells of array by keyPressed()?

Tags: processing, processing.js

I try to make a web application. 
You can change cells of the array by pressing arrow keys [here](https://demsp.github.io/processing_arr.html). 
There is a class "Module" with methods display() and update(). These methods change the inner array data[].

```java
class Module {
    int i; // index
    int x; // coordinate 
    int y; // coordinate 
    int[] data = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0};

    // Contructor
    Module(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    void update() {
        data[i]=_mas_stor;
    } 

    void display(){
        text(data[i], x, 100);
    }
}
```

But how to set the initial value of the array `_mass[]` at the beginning of the program?

The whole program [here](https://github.com/demsp/demsp.github.io/blob/master/processing_arr.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of an array of `data` in the class `Module`. It is sufficient that each object has it single data member. Wirte a constructor, eher you can pass to the initial data (`Module(int x, int d)`):

```
class Module {
    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
    int data;
    // Contructor
    Module(int x, int d){
        this.x = x;
        this.data = d;
    }
    void update() {
        data=_mas[global_i];
    }    
    void display(){
        textSize(30);
        text(data, x, 100);
    }
}
```

Now the object can be initialized in a loop with ease:

```
int[] _mas ={1,2,3,4,5};
int global_i = 0;
Module [] mods;

void setup() {
    size(500, 400);
    mods = new Module[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i ) {
        mods[i] = new Module(i*50+50, _mas[i]);
    }
}
```

Further you have to ensure that `global_i` doesn't go out of bounds in `keyPressed`:

```
void keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode == UP) {
        _mas[global_i]++;
    } 
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        _mas[global_i]--;
    }
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        global_i--; 
        if (global_i < 0)
            global_i = 4;
    } 
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        global_i++;
        if (global_i > 4)
            global_i = 0;
    } 
}
```

---

Note, you can further improve you program, if you skip the global variable `_mas` and add a increment method (`inc`) and decrement method (`dec`) to the class `Module`, instead of the `update` method:

```
int global_i = 0;
Module [] mods;

void setup() {
    size(500, 400);
    mods = new Module[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i ) {
        mods[i] = new Module(i*50+50, i);
    }
}

void draw() {
    background(50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i ) {
        mods[i].display();
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode == UP) {
        println("up");
        mods[global_i].inc();
    } 
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        mods[global_i].dec();
    }
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        global_i--; 
        if (global_i < 0)
            global_i = 4;
    } 
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        global_i++;
        if (global_i > 4)
            global_i = 0;
    } 
}

class Module {
    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
    int data;
    // Contructor
    Module(int x, int d){
        this.x = x;
        this.data = d;
    }   
    void inc() {
        this.data ++;
    }
    void dec() {
        this.data --;
    }
    void display(){
        textSize(30);
        text(data, x, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually set the initial value of an array using a `for` loop. Something like this:

```
String myArray = new String[10];
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  myArray[i] = "hello world";
}
```

What you put inside the `for` loop depends on what values you want your array to start with.